# PHP: Foreach with "if-else" statement

Tags: php, if-statement, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I'm doing some changes on an online store that is running OpenCart 2.2.
When browsing below the categories on the left side, there are 2 carousels that show different promotions. I want to modify it that before the second carousel there is a description text. To do that I should edit the template file. And here is where I get lost..
This is the code in the template file:

```
<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

From I see in the browser inspector and in my case, this code generates 2 banners with the ids - "banner0" and "banner1". The description text should go at the top of the code (right before ). If I use a simple paragraph, it gets displayed twice - above each banner.. How should I change it so that it will display the paragraph only above the second banner (id - banner1)?
I was thinking about an if-else statement, but I'm not sure if that will work... Could anyone help out a bit? My knowledge in PHP isn't much... :S

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Tsvetko Krastev

Answer (score 1):

If I get the code right, `$module` is 0/1 (if id's get values `banner0` and `banner1`), then this should work:

```
<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
      <?php if ($module == "1") { ?>
          <p>Your description</p>
      <?php } ?>
    <div class="item">
        <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to know that this is the second time round the foreach loop. So change the foreach to include the index like this, and add a test inside the loop for `$i == 1`

```
<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">

  <?php //foreach ($banners as $banner) { 
        foreach ($banners as $i => $banner) { 
  ?>


  <div class="item">

    <?php if ($banner['link']) { 
        if ( $i == 1 ) {
            echo 'YOUR HTML CONTAINING SOME TEXT HERE';
        }
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so very much guys!!! Tried both versions and they throw a error, but looking more carefully into the code and both your solutions, I came up with this:

```
<div id="desc<?php echo $module; ?>">
    <?php if ($module == 1) { ?>
        <p>Description</p>
    <?php } ?>
<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much again for the quick responses and the help! :) :3

Best regards,
Tsvetko Krastev